# Cannot keyframe multiple bones

Tags: keyframes, nla-editor

Hey guys i have a little problem with keyfreaming.
Anytime i select some bones in pose mode, rotate them and hit [I] on the rotation properties, blender inserts only one keyframe for one bone, the one i selected first, at the same time the Outliner shows that multiple bones are selected. I'm using NLA, and the problem above started when i pushed down the animation i had done first. I tried with a blank project and it worked like normal.

im using the latest version of blender.
What can i be missing out?

Thanks for your help:)

Ákos

Comment: maybe make sure you haven't locked the bones tracks?

Comment: There are multiple different things that might cause this.  You could have locked tracks in the NLA; as @moonboots suggested; you could have a keying set that is excluding some bones; the animation you pushed down could still be active, et cetera.  Can you add your blend file to your question? (([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: There was an active keying set, i had no idea about. Thanks guys for advice, it works now:)